# Can Oracle JDBC 11g R2 (11.2.0.3) driver connect to Oracle 10g R10 db

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I am about to install JDBC 11g R2 driver to connect to Oracle 10g release 10.2.0.4 64bit server.
Is the choice of driver correct ?

Comment: If in doubt read the documentation: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#02_02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, no problem, you can connect with 11g jdbc driver to 10g.